# Float left and right not working

Tags: jquery, css, html

> http://jsfiddle.net/S2fe9/
>   the  containers should be next to each other but are coming after line break

```
    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">


    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h2>Audi A8</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="paintarea">

        <div id="painttext" class="pt">
            <h3>
                <b>Paint</b>
            </h3>
            <p>We believe that every part of your car should have a personal
                touch. Which is why you can choose from a wide range of paint
                colours and finishes, from standard shades to metallic and pearl
                effects.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="paintcolor" class="pc">
                      <b>Paint</b>
            </h3>
            <p>We believe that every part of your car should have a personal
                touch. Which is why you can choose from a wide range of paint
                colours and finishes, from standard shades to metallic and pearl
                effects.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`padding-right` & `padding-left` adds extra width to your container try to make calculations before applying. try This Code.: now the total width is coming out to be 100%, if you exceed 100% then it will go to next line.

**CSS**:

```
#paintarea
{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#painttext {
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: interword;
}

#paintcolor
{
    width: 50%;

}

.pt
{
    float: left;
}
.pc
{
    float: left;
}
```

**Updated Fiddle**:
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/S2fe9/1/)

Comment: m glad that it helped u. You can mark it as answer.

Comment: Was trying to do it earlier but it popped that you cannot mark it as a answer within 2 Mins, Lol.!

Answer (score 0):

Try updating below CSS:

```
#painttext {
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 85px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: interword; }
```

Actually width was applied wrongly and was overlapping other div

Check updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/7sYXb/)

Comment: Thanks mate, i guess playing with % is easy as mentioned by @Shaminder

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**HTML :**

```
 <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>Audi A8</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="paintarea">
      <div id="painttext" class="pt">
        <h3> <b>Paint</b></h3>

        <p>We believe that every part of your car should have a personal touch. Which is       
           why you can choose from a wide range of paint colours and finishes, from 
           standard shades to metallic and pearl effects.</p>
       </div>

    <div id="paintcolor" class="pc">
         <h3><b>Paint</b></h3>

        <p>We believe that every part of your car should have a personal touch. Which is 
           why you can choose from a wide range of paint colours and finishes, from 
           standard shades to metallic and pearl effects.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
  #paintarea {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
   #painttext {
   width: 20%;
   padding-top: 85px;
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;
   text-align: justify;
   text-justify: interword;
   }
   #paintcolor {    
   width: 55%;
   }
  .pt {
   float: left;
   }
  .pc {
   float: right;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
#paintarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#painttext {
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: interword;
 }

#paintcolor
{
    width: 50%;
}

.pt
{
    float: left;
}

.pc
{
    float: left;
}
```